# How to add a 2-times derived class of TCollectionItem to TOwnedCollection?

Tags: c++builder, vcl, tcollectionitem, townedcollection

I want to implement a collection or list using TOwnedCollection / TCollectionItem. I need a persistent list (to load and create from a FileStream) of classes with polymorphism.

Here is (part of) my code so far, but I didn't succeed to create the derived class TGenerator instead of its parent TPowerComponent and add it to the Collection.

```cpp
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TPCCollection : public TOwnedCollection
    {
            typedef TOwnedCollection inherited;
    private:
            TPowerComponent* __fastcall GetPowerComponent(int Index);
            void __fastcall SetPowerComponent(int Index, TPowerComponent *Value);

    public:
            __fastcall TPCCollection(TPersistent *Owner);

            HIDESBASE TPowerComponent* __fastcall Add(void);
            HIDESBASE TPowerComponent* __fastcall Insert(int Index);

            __property TPowerComponent* PCCollection[int Index] = {read=GetPowerComponent, write=SetPowerComponent};
};

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TPowerComponent : public TCollectionItem
{
    typedef TCollectionItem inherited;
public :
    int X, Y, Rotation;
    PowSymbType HisType;

    __fastcall TPowerComponent(TCollection *Collection, PowSymbType AType );
    void __fastcall Assign(TPersistent *Source);
    virtual void __fastcall Paint(TCanvas * Canvas);
};
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TGenerator : public TPowerComponent
{
            typedef TPowerComponent inherited;
public :
    double PG, Qgmin, Qgmax, Vsch;

    __fastcall TGenerator(TCollection *Collection, PowSymbType AType );
    void __fastcall Assign(TPersistent *Source);
    virtual void __fastcall Paint(TCanvas * Canvas);    
    };
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// implementation
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  TPCCOllection
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TPCCollection::TPCCollection(TPersistent *Owner)
        : TOwnedCollection(Owner, __classid(TPowerComponent))
{
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TPowerComponent* __fastcall TPCCollection::Add()
{
    return static_cast<TPowerComponent>(inherited::Add());
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TPowerComponent* __fastcall TPCCollection::Insert(int Index)
{
    return static_cast<TPowerComponent>(inherited::Insert(Index));
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TPowerComponent* __fastcall TPCCollection::GetPowerComponent(int Index)
{
    return static_cast<TPowerComponent>(inherited::GetItem(Index));
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TPCCollection::SetPowerComponent(int Index, TPowerComponent *Value)
{
    inherited::SetItem(Index, Value);
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  TPowerComponent
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TPowerComponent::TPowerComponent(TCollection *Collection, PowSymbType AType )
        : TCollectionItem(Collection)
{
    HisType=AType;
    Rotation=0;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TPowerComponent::Assign(TPersistent *Source)
{
    TPowerComponent *Src = dynamic_cast<TPowerComponent>(Source);
    if( Src )
        {
                // copy members from Src...
        }
    else    inherited::Assign(Source);
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// se dessine
void __fastcall TPowerComponent::Paint(TCanvas * Canvas)
{
...
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  TGenerator
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TGenerator::TGenerator(TCollection *Collection, PowSymbType AType )
        :TPowerComponent( Collection, AType )
{
    PG=0; Qgmin=0; Qgmax=0; Vsch=1.0; Con=-1;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TGenerator::Assign(TPersistent *Source)
{
    TGenerator *Src = dynamic_cast<TGenerator>(Source);
    if( Src )
        {
                // copy members from Src...
        }
    else    inherited::Assign(Source);
}



//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Usage 
TPCCollection * NetWork = new TPCCollection(this);

//  Usage to Access all the collection
for( int i=0; i< NetWork->Count; i++)
    {
    ((TPowerComponent*)(NetWork->Items[i]))->Paint(Canvas);
    }
```

To add a TGenerator and not a TPowerComponent, I use:

```cpp
TGenerator * Gen=new TGenerator( NetWork, Generator);
```

The creation of the TCollectionItem child automatically add itself to the TCollection

The problem here is that we can't separate the process of item creation from adding it to the collection.

When I need another list that can have some of the items of the first collection list, for example, SelectedComponents can have one or some of the Items of the NetWork Collection, without recreating them.

This can be done with

```cpp
std::list<TPowerComponent*> SelectedComponents;
```

but I can't write/read them using FileStream / persistent list. I need to put them in a TCollection but without recreating them.

How?

Comment: I edited my question to fulfil moderator recommendation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RTL's native DFM streaming for `TCollection` objects only partially supports polymorphic `TCollectionItem` classes.

You can add polymorphic `TCollectionItem` objects to a `TCollection` in code (at runtime, as well as at design-time with the aid of a custom editor), as long as they all derive from a common base class that is passed to the `TCollection` constructor.  And such a collection can even be saved as-is to a DFM.

However, when loading back a DFM, native streaming will force all collection items read from the DFM to use whatever `TCollectionItem` class type you pass to the `TCollection` constructor.  So, polymorphic classes can't be loaded natively.

The only way to override that behavior is to disable native streaming for the collection (make your `TCollection` property be non-`published`, or at least mark it as `stored=false`), and then stream the collection items manually.

Have your main component (or whatever `TPersistent` class owns the collection) override the virtual [`DefineProperties()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TComponent.DefineProperties) method to call [`TFiler.DefineProperty()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TFiler.DefineProperty) to register custom reading/writing methods for streaming the collection items. To support polymorphic classes, you will have to write each item's `ClassName` to the DFM before writing its property values, then read the name back so you know which class to instantiate before then reading property values.

Comment: My TPowerComponent and their childs are not to be part of a TForm like Tbuttons or... so if I understand you, I don't even need a TCollection/TCollectionItem classes to handle them? and write them on a stream? but how when I read the object from the Stream (manually) I can figure out which child it is (TGenerator, TLoad, TLIne...)?

Comment: You don't need to use `TCollection`/`TCollectionItem` unless you want to support design-time editing or DFM streaming. As for streaming, as I said in my answer, you have to write a child's class type name to the stream before writing it's values. When you read back the stream, you have to read a child's class type name first to know which class to instantiate for the child before then reading its values.